# Google Play Game Services BaseGameUtils bug

Tags: android, google-play-games

I made an Android project in which I'd like to use GPGS. I set up the project, made some achievements. I use the `BaseGameUtils` library as a base. At the start, the application asks for which account I'd like to use, and everything is going well.
I could open the Achievements activity with this code:

```
if (gameHelper.isSignedIn()) {
    startActivityForResult(Games.Achievements.getAchievementsIntent(gameHelper.getApiClient()), 101);
} else if (!gameHelper.isConnecting()) {
    loginGPGS();
}
```

However if I'm there, and I open the options menu in that activity and sign out, and I'm trying to open the achievements again, my application crashes with a message about I should log in before trying to get them. And while this is true, I assumed the `gameHelper.isSignedIn()` should only return true, if the user is logged in. Is the `BaseGameUtils` broken, or am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the exact issue brought up [on the Github issue tracker](https://github.com/playgameservices/android-basic-samples/issues/121). The final response was:

> This is actually not a bug - it's working as intended.
>
> When you start a GPGS activity, you have to start it with `startActivityForResult`. If the user clicks on sign-out, the `GoogleApiClient` is NOT disconnected - it's just in a "signed out" state. The `onActivityResult` here will return a status `RECONNECT_REQUIRED`. At this point, the developer should reconnect their client, and life goes on as expected.